# Load all elements from a vector

Tags: c++

So these codes are a part from a game. The loading of resource paths are stored intro a vector, and is loaded by specifyng mob vnum.

Example :

```
If (vnum === 99)
    std::string = "Path/path/vnum_99_folder"
```

That's my code

```
void GetRaceResourcePathes(unsigned vnum, std::vector <std::string> &vec_stPathes)
{
    if (vnum >= 30000)
    {
        vec_stPathes.push_back("d:/work/npc2/");
        vec_stPathes.push_back("d:/work/npc/");
        vec_stPathes.push_back("d:/work/monster/");
        vec_stPathes.push_back("d:/work/monster2/");
    }
    else
    {
        vec_stPathes.push_back("d:/work/npc/");
        vec_stPathes.push_back("d:/work/npc2/");
        vec_stPathes.push_back("d:/work/monster/");
        vec_stPathes.push_back("d:/work/monster2/");
    }
}
```

The above code is with resource paths, stored intro a vector.. then return the size and load paths.

Here is where

```
CRaceData* CRaceManager::LoadRaceData(DWORD vnum)
{
    auto fRaceName = m_kMap_dwRaceKey_stRaceName.find(vnum);

    if (m_kMap_dwRaceKey_stRaceName.end() == fRaceName)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    auto &c_rstRaceName = fRaceName->second;

    if (c_rstRaceName.empty())
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    std::vector <std::string> vec_stFullPathName;
    GetRaceResourcePathes(vnum, vec_stFullPathName);

    CRaceData* pRaceData = CRaceData::New();
    pRaceData->SetRace(vnum);

    for (int i = 0; i < vec_stFullPathName.size(); i++)
    {
        std::string stFullPathName = vec_stFullPathName[i];
        {
            auto RaceSrcName = m_kMap_stRaceName_stSrcName.find(c_rstRaceName);

            if (m_kMap_stRaceName_stSrcName.end() == RaceSrcName)
            {
                stFullPathName += c_rstRaceName;
            }
            else
            {
                stFullPathName += RaceSrcName->second;
            }
        }

        stFullPathName += "/";
        std::string stMSMFileName = stFullPathName + c_rstRaceName + ".msm";

        if (!pRaceData->LoadRaceData(stMSMFileName.c_str()))
        {
            if (i != vec_stFullPathName.size() - 1)
            {
                TraceError("CRaceManager::RegisterRacePath : vnum[%u] LOAD MSMFILE[%s] ERROR. Will Find Another Path.", vnum, stMSMFileName.c_str());
                continue;
            }

            TraceError("CRaceManager::RegisterRacePath : vnum[%u] LOAD MSMFILE[%s] ERROR", vnum, stMSMFileName.c_str());
            CRaceData::Delete(pRaceData);
            return NULL;
        }

        std::string stMotionListFileName = stFullPathName;
        stMotionListFileName += pRaceData->GetMotionListFileName();

        LoadRaceMotionList(*pRaceData, stFullPathName.c_str(), stMotionListFileName.c_str());
        return pRaceData;
    }

    TraceError("CRaceManager::RegisterRacePath : vnum[%u] HAVE NO PATH ERROR", vnum);
    CRaceData::Delete(pRaceData);
    return NULL;
}
```

I want to remove those vnum == checks.. and load the all the paths in same time.. without specifying the vnum..

```
void GetRaceResourcePathes(unsigned vnum, std::vector <std::string> &vec_stPathes)
{
    vec_stPathes.push_back("d:/work/npc/");
    vec_stPathes.push_back("d:/work/npc2/");
    vec_stPathes.push_back("d:/work/monster/");
    vec_stPathes.push_back("d:/work/monster2/");
}
```

If i change the `GetRaceResourcePathes` like above, will be loaded only first line...  "work/npc/" the other 3 are ignored..

What is wrong? Why not all 4 paths are loaded?

Answer (score 2):

Your line:

```
return pRaceData;
```

is returning from inside the for loop. So the loop never continues after the first iteration, and the `LoadRaceData` function will return the result of the first load.

Comment: "What is wrong? Why not all 4 paths are loaded?" - this answer explains the problem - as for what the code is actually trying to do, that's a different question, and one that's hard to answer without a lot more information about your problem.

Comment: I will try to make 4 loops for now, each one with a path